# XSLT Combine two XMLs and produce multiple outputs

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the following XMLs:

car.xml:

```
<car ref-id="parts.xml" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <color>red</color>
  <engine>
    <model>Z</model>
  </engine>
</car>
```

parts.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<parts xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <engines>
    <engine>
      <model>X</model>
    </engine>
    <engine>
      <model>Y</model>
    </engine>
  </engines>
</parts>
```

For the desired result I need to produce 3 output files:

```
<car xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <color>red</color>
  <engine>
    <model>X</model>
  </engine>
</car>

<car xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <color>red</color>
  <engine>
    <model>Y</model>
  </engine>
</car>

<car xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <color>red</color>
  <engine>
    <model>Z</model>
  </engine>
</car>
```

I'm stuck with the transformation, so far I have this one to combine the two XMLs, but no clue how to separate the result into multiple output files:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:variable name="loc">
        <xsl:value-of select="car/@ref-id" />
    </xsl:variable>


    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:variable name="lookup-document" select="document($loc)/parts/engines" />
        <xsl:copy-of select="*" />
        <xsl:copy-of select="$lookup-document/*" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Answer (score 0):

XSLT 1.0 does not support multiple output files as a result of a single transformation. If your processor supports it, you can use the EXSLT  [exsl:document](http://exslt.org/exsl/elements/document/index.html) extension element. Otherwise you'll have to perform three individual transformations.

Comment: I cannot find any XSLT1.0 compliant processor for java that supports exsl:document. It worth to use XLST 2.0 and `xsl:result-document` instead ?

Comment: @Bruckwald "*I cannot find any XSLT1.0 compliant processor for java that supports exsl:document.*" I don't believe there is one, although Saxon 6.5 supports its own `saxon:output` extension,as well as the XSLT 1.1 `xsl:document` element. -- "*It worth to use XLST 2.0 and xsl:result-document instead ?*" If you *can* use XSLT 2.0, why would you not want to?